# How to add user control in tab control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

The below article shows how to create dynamic tabs in WPF, that in each tab it will add just one text box.

```
private TabItem AddTabItem()
{
    int count = _tabItems.Count;

    // create new tab item
    TabItem tab = new TabItem();

    tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
    tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);
    tab.HeaderTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;

    tab.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(tab_MouseDoubleClick);

    // add controls to tab item, this case I added just a textbox
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();

    txt.Name = "txt";
    tab.Content = txt;
    // insert tab item right before the last (+) tab item
    _tabItems.Insert(count - 1, tab);

    return tab;
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493538/Add-Remove-Tabs-Dynamically-in-WPF

what can I do for adding some complex controls that their positions are fixed instead of just 1 text box? can I create a user control for this purpose? so how can I add the user control to tab control?

Answer (score 5):

Try the next steps:

1. Add a user control (Lets say in ComplexControl.xaml)

   ```
   <UserControl ... >
      <Grid>
          <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red"/>
       </Grid>
    </UserControl>
   ```
2. Create a class

   ```
   Public myComplexContolClass
   {
        //....
   }
   ```
3. Map them together so when you have a myComplexContolClass in your app visually it will be the UserControl from 1. The map can be done
   with DataTemplate:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                       ...
                       xmlns:models="clr-namespace: ... .Model"
                       xmlns:views="clr-namespace: ... .View"
                       >

       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:myComplexContolClass}">
           <views:ComplexControl/>
       </DataTemplate>

   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

Or

```
    <Window ...
            xmlns:models="clr-namespace: ... .Model"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace: ... .View"
            >

        <Window.Resources>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:myComplexContolClass}">
                <views:ComplexControl/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </Window.Resources>

        // ...

    </Window>
```

4. Add it to your code:

   ```
   private TabItem AddTabItem()
   {
       // ...

       myComplexContolClass control = new myComplexContolClass();
       tab.Content = control;

       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes I know but when I add these to my xaml file, the resources will add automatically.

Comment: please look at this source file : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493538/Add-Remove-Tabs-Dynamically-in-WPF I want to change this.